# Intersection of nested dense subsets.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $(A_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of subsets of the topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ such that

1. $A_1$ is dense in $X$.
2. $A_{n+1}$ is dense in $A_n$.

is $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ dense in $X$?

Comment: 1. and 2. can be equivalently replaced by: $A_n$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @julien: I think 1 & 2 imply $A_n$ is dense in $X$. But if the $A_n$ are dense in $X$, are 1 & 2 true?

Comment: If $A_{n+1}$ is dense in $X$, then $A_{n+1}$ is a fortiori dense in any set that contains it, eg $A_n$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $\{r_n,n\in\Bbb N\}$ an enumeration of rationals and $X_n:=\{r_k,k\geqslant n\}$. Each $X_n$ is dense in $X:=\Bbb R$ for the usual topology, but the intersection is empty.

Answer (score 12):

HINT: Let $\{q_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $A_n=\{q_k:k\ge n\}$. What is $\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n$?

Answer (score 5):

The best counterexample has already been given.

Let me simply point out that if your property holds for every such sequence $A_n$, then in particular $X$ would have to be a [Baire space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space).

And there exist topological spaces which are not Baire spaces.

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space), a typical counterexample is $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology induced by the metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks. also mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire

Comment: @CutieKrait not quite, you are looking for a Baire space, not a set with the property of Baire. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for this useful precision.