# Intersection of certain dense subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: general-topology

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathbb{C}^n \supseteq A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq \cdots$
be a countable decreasing chain of subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Assume that each $A_i$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, is a *dense* subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Denote $A=\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}A_i$.

> What can be said about $A$? In particular: Is $A$ dense in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Any hints and comments are welcome!

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318762/intersection-of-nested-dense-subsets) question is somewhat relevant.

Comment: It could be empty, just like in the linked question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $A_i$ are open, we can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem.

Comment: Thank you! Please, could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Baire spaces were basically invented to answer the question of whether an intersection of dense sets is still dense. The answer is affirmative for Baire spaces, and we use the Baire Category theorem. A **complete metrizable topological space** is a Baire space, for example. $\mathbb{C}^n$ satisfies this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Interesting.

Comment: As Angina stated, the same examples for the post you linked also apply here, so there's not much we can say until we add some assumptions.

Comment: ok, thank you. So the $A_i$'s being open is a possible additional assumption that guarantees that $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Could one find another additional assumption in our specific space $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: I think open might be the best you can do to guarantee it's still dense, but I'm open to being wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113135/discussion-between-user203940-and-user237522).